# Periodic function with linear term and next term is degree 5 term

Tags: functions

I am looking for an smooth, odd periodic function with a linear term and for which the taylor expansion does not have a degree 3 term. Does this exist? What is this function?

Comment: @Surajit Not periodic! (What happens as $x$ gets really large?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the function to have a Taylor series valid for all $x$. So the obvious choice is something built on sine functions. For example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I suppose to achieve next degree 7, I require 4 different sines? Or can one achieve it with 3?

Comment: @Rascalniikov You can do it with three sines: $\sin x-\frac{1}{5}\sin2x+\frac{1}{45}\sin3x$ giving $\frac{2}{3}x-\frac{1}{210}x^7+\frac{1}{1080}x^9+\dots$.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Take one odd smooth periodic function $f(x)$, and another $g(x)$, then take $h(x)=Af(x)+Bg(x)$. So long as the functions are not linearly dependent, you can select $A$ and $B$ such that $h$ will not have a degree $3$ term.

For example, you can take $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $g(x)=\sin^3(x)$. Now, since $f(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6} + \cdots$ and $g(x)=x^3+\cdots$, you can take $A=6, B=1$ to get $$6f(x)+g(x)=6x + 0\cdot x^3 + \cdots$$